# Google login not working for amazon app store app

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin, amazon-appstore

Google login not working on amazon app store app.
I have uploaded the same APK in amazon, google login is working fine when I download app from play store and app store but it is not working when I download from amazon app store.

Is there any SHA-1 key in amazon app store I have tried to find but I did not get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Amazon Appstore re-sign your app with a signature which is unique to your Amazon developer account. You can get the hash keys by going to your app submission, select the **APK Files** tab, and there's a link **Appstore Certificate Hashes** in the upper right corner.

Comment: Thank you, It is really helpful.
I found all keys here and attached the SHA-1 key to my firebase project and now it is working fine.

Comment: great! glad to hear :)